# Stripe retrieves invoices for all customers - not the one specified

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

I'm using the following code to get the invoices created by the specified customer:

```
customer.invoices.all
```

But it retrieves all the invoices regardless of which customer created them. I also tried the following:

```
Stripe::Invoice.all(customer: CUSTOMER_ID)
```

And it behaves the same way. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 10/23/2020**

The new Stripe API requires the following:

```
Stripe::Invoice.list(customer: CUSTOMER_ID)
```

**Original Answer**

It looks like like calling `all` on invoices overrides the previous query where it retrieves the invoices for the customer.

The following retrieves all invoices:

```
customer.invoices.all
```

The following retrieves all invoices for the customer only:

```
customer.invoices
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Stripe::Invoice.all(:customer => "CUSTOMER_ID")
```

From the API: https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#list_customer_invoices

Comment: According to the original question, I have already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like

```
  customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_6C09m0rCIx3Ld8")
  invoices = Stripe::Invoice.all(:customer => customer.id)
```